# bot framwork call UserMessagesAsync by resume dialog prompt

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework, chat, chatbot

Hi I am a newbie coding a chatbot framework. 
I have main entry method `UserMessagesAsync` which handle user messages if a user sends a message that match 
the condition. This is my code:
**how to call UserMessagesAsync inside ChoiceReceivedAsync**

```
 private async Task UserMessagesAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            if (activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("outlet"))
            {
                new BusinessDialog().OutletPrompt(context, result).Wait();

            }
            else if (activity.Text.ToLower().Contains("materialcost"))
            {
                string url = "url";
                await context.PostAsync(url);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
            }
        }
```

`OutletPrompt` code:

```
 public async Task OutletPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Object> result)
        {
            PromptDialog.Choice(
               context: context,
               resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
               options: (IEnumerable<Outlet>)Enum.GetValues(typeof(Outlet)),
               prompt: "Hi. Please Select one :",
               retry: "Please try again.",
               promptStyle: PromptStyle.Keyboard
               );
        }
```

the `Outlet` enum:

```
public enum Outlet
        {
            DocumentRepository,
            Branches
        }
```

resume function:

```
 public virtual async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Domstic> activity)
        {
            // how to call UserMessagesAsync
        }
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: how to call UserMessagesAsync inside ChoiceReceivedAsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```cs
public virtual async Task ChoiceReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<Domstic> activity)
{
    await UserMessagesAsync(context, activity as IAwaitable<Domstic>);
}
```

That being said, I hope you haven't done too much work with this, yet.

## You should use [BotFramework SDK v4](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet), not v3

- [v3 is deprecated, no new bots can be created in Azure, and there will be no new features or non-critical bug fixes for it in the future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-bot-framework-faq?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-framework-sdk-version-3-lifetime-support-and-deprecation-notice)
- v3 is very, very outdated now
- v4 has a lot of new features and is continually updated

[Get started with v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-sdk-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

[Migrate from v3 to v4](https://aka.ms/bfv3v4migration)

Comment: Thanks for your helpful **advice** but i'm trying `await UserMessagesAsync(context, activity as IAwaitable<Object>);` the bot emulator send **Sorry, my bot code is having an issue.** @mdrichardson

Comment: @KarimFahmy Can you share all of your code? This is difficult to track down or troubleshoot without it. Still, if you haven't put too much effort into the v3 bot, you should definitely switch to v4.

Comment: i will switch to v4, thanks for your help @mdrichardson - MSFT

Comment: @KarimFahmy Did you find my answer adequate, then? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!